# Would the commas in the phrase, "Hurry up, hurry up, hurry up," be a comma splice?

Tags: commas

The question is just as the title says. Here are a few examples:

> "Come on, come on, come on!"
>
> "Go, go, go, go, go!"
>
> "Hurry up, hurry up, hurry up!"

Would these be comma splices?

Comment: It might help to picture that you would say each of your examples in one breath.  Still unclear?  "No, no, no."

Answer (score 1):

The commas themselves aren't a comma splice--it's the clauses that would be. But it's not a comma splice anyway, because very short phrases (like "Easy come, easy go" or "here today, gone tomorrow") can be joined in that way to form acceptable sentences, at least acceptable to me.

Answer (score 0):

Since those phrases are not [independent clauses](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/598/01/), I'd say no those commas are not comma splices.